# Django - Live update with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

Here is current workflow:

1. In django admin someone adds data to model/form.
2. That starts
   python code which runs completely in background and can take up to
   5min to finish. Without console access they can't see what's going
   on.
3. They have to wait and refresh site to see results.

I am thinking about something like displaying "progress"(done this, done that, error here) via bootstrap's notifications (js).

Have hard time wrapping my head around how to get data from python to JS(first time doing this) would appreciate any pointers or useful links.

Edit: I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsorlkAF83s explains it great detail if anyone will be interested in the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could mention how far you achieve then it will be easy to figure out the answer... Anyway my answer is general at all...

First you have to use `signal` for tracking the database if any new entry it will activate and trigger your python code...

Secondly the best way to communicate with frontend is websockets and recent `Mozilla` Support for Django promise `websocket` into the core.

follow this guide for more info about the django [channels](http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)